# How to correct date format while parsing

Tags: sql, performance, spool

I am converting SQL TABLE data into txt format. Only half of the data is successfully converted and remaining data showing 2 error...
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
And Document not found

Comment: How about letting us know the command you are using to do the conversion and the sample data that is causing the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.